# Как запустить Selenium+Java+Cucumber без ide

Tags: java, selenium, ide, cucumber

Здравствуйте имеются тесты написанные на java + cucumber

Структура следующая:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyJpo.png

Главный вопрос, как запустить это добро не из IDE, а скажем из консоли или вообще обернуть это все в jar файл

Проблемы с которыми столкнулся это то что для создания jar нужен класс main,

Вроде как существует некий java cucumber.api.cli.Main - но как этим пользоваться я пока не понял. В любом случае наверняка есть способ запустить это просто из командной строки. Расскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: Собери джарник и запускай его java -jar
Только не забудь указать в pom.xml чтобы библиотеки так же собрались

Comment: jar требует main класс, а такового нет. Как быть?

Comment: а почему ты не хочешь использовать main?)
у тебя maven не знает где точка входа в приложение

Comment: @Mark100F а как ты запускаешь свое приложение из ide?

Answer (score 1):

Создание исполняемого JAR файла с помощью Maven
Задача
Создать исполняемый JAR файл для запуска программы из командной строки

Решение
Для создания исполняемого JAR файла необходимо указать главный класс (Main-Class) в файле манифеста (META-INF/manifest.mf). Указываемый класс является точкой входа приложения.

При использовании Maven это можно сделать посредством maven-jar-plugin. Для этого необходимо объявить данный плагин в pom.xml и в разделе конфигурации плагина указать главный класс

```
<build>

  <plugins>

      <!-- Maven JAR Plugin --> 
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>ru.javacore.myapp.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

  </plugins>

</build>
```

Теперь при сборке проекта, в файле манифеста будет добавляться строка:
`Main-Class: ru.javacore.myapp.Main`

Для запуска программы из командной строки будет достаточно указать имя JAR файла:
`java -jar myapp.jar`

Чтобы объявить зависимые библиотеки у JAR файла необходимо указать заголовок Class-Path в файле манифеста. Для этого в плагине при настройке манифеста объявляется элемент addClasspath. Если зависимые библиотеки располагаются в отдельной папке, то эту папку следует указать в элементе classpathPrefix.

```
      <!-- Maven JAR Plugin --> 
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>ru.javacore.myapp.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```